# Can you convert a string to the name of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm trying to take the input from someone, `commandName.substring(7)` and immediately put `context['display-name']` into the array which matches the name of the input.

```
var pokemon = [];
var Grookey = [];
pokemon.push(Grookey);
var Thwackey = [];
pokemon.push(Thwackey);
var Rillaboom = [];
pokemon.push(Rillaboom);

function addPokemon () {
  var adding = commandName.substring(7);
  adding.push(context['display-name']);
}
```

Is there any way of doing this besides

```
if (commandName.substring(7) === "Grookey"){
  pokemon[0].push(context['display-name']);
}
```

This is being used for twitch chat where `context['display-name']` is the user's @. For example, !trade Grookey would cause `pokemon[[Phalanx],[],[]]` to happen.

Comment: What is `context`? Also note that there is nothing in `pokemon` that references the name `Grookey`. If you look at `pokemon`, you would would see `[[],[],[]]`. Use an object with property names.

Comment: does pokemon  have to be an array? could it be an Object?

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary (object):

```
var pokemon = {
  'Grookey': [],
  'Thwackey': [],
  'Rillaboom': []
};

function addPokemon () {
  var adding = commandName.substring(7);
  // adding might be Grookey, Thwackey or Rillaboom...
  pokemon[adding].push(context['display-name']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain why you need use array of array? Let's try use object like this

```
const pokemon = {
    Grookey: [],
    Thwackey: [],
    Rillaboom: []
}
```

and then

```
    pokemon[commandName].push(context['display-name']);
```